# How to make a select from a table and from relative xml column while splitting into rows the XML column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, cross-apply

I have a table T with two columns.
Column A is a varchar column and Column B is a XML column.

Somewhere inside Column B there is always the following parent tag: `<Documents> ... </Documents>`. Inside there are many `<Document>...</Document>` children.

I would like to get a result set with two columns:

- Column 1 should contain the same values of Column A;
- Column 2 should contain the content of one `<Document>...</Document>` only.

E.g. Starting table T:

```
Column A | Column B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc      | <Documents><Document>Doc 1</Document><Document>Doc 2</Document></Documents>
```

Expected result:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------------------------
abc      |<Document>Doc 1</Document>
abc      |<Document>Doc 2</Document>
```

I can get Column 2 like this (as seen in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
SELECT T2.C.query('.')
FROM T
CROSS APPLY T.[Column B].nodes('*/Documents/*') as T (C)
```

but this does not work instead:

```
SELECT T.[Column A], T2.C.query('.')
FROM T
CROSS APPLY T.[Column B].nodes('*/Documents/*') as T2 (C)
```

How to get the expected result then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID CHAR(3), xmldata XML);;
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, xmldata)
VALUES
('abc', '<Documents><Document>Doc 1</Document><Document>Doc 2</Document></Documents>')
, ('xyz', '<Documents><Document>Doc 10</Document><Document>Doc 20</Document></Documents>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.query('.') AS [Column 2]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('//Documents/Document') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+-----+-----------------------------+
| ID  |          Column 2           |
+-----+-----------------------------+
| abc | <Document>Doc 1</Document>  |
| abc | <Document>Doc 2</Document>  |
| xyz | <Document>Doc 10</Document> |
| xyz | <Document>Doc 20</Document> |
+-----+-----------------------------+
```